# An entropy inequality: $h_{\mu}(\beta,T)\leq h_{\mu}(\alpha,T)+H_{\mu}(\beta|\alpha)$

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory, entropy

Let T be a measure preserving transformation on the probability space $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$.

I have already solved this problem:

Suppose $\alpha$ is a finite partition of $X$. Show that $h_{\mu}(\alpha, T) = h_{\mu}(\bigvee_{i=1}^n T^{-i}\alpha,T)$
for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

But after a day I could not find a solution to the next one:

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be finite partitions. Show that $h_{\mu}(\beta,T)\leq h_{\mu}(\alpha,T)+H_{\mu}(\beta|\alpha)$

I think it is undoable to do it by using the definition of entropies.
Since $h_{\mu}(\alpha,T)\leq H_{\mu}(\alpha)$ and $H_{\mu}(\beta|\alpha) = H_{\mu}(\alpha\vee\beta)-H_{\mu}(\alpha)$, it suffices to show

$H_{\mu}(\beta)+H_{\mu}(\alpha)\leq h_{\mu}(\alpha,T)+H_{\mu}(\alpha\vee\beta)$

Maybe the previous problem should be used, but the next problem (c) says "use parts a and b to show...", so it is not very likely.

Is there anyone who can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No answer needed anymore because I already found the answer here: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~francois.le-maitre/gdt/KS.pdf

Comment: delete question then

Comment: @mathworker21 I'd rather not delete the question, because the answer in the link could also be useful for others.